# postgresql extract non alpha numeric

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to return the non-alpha numeric characters in my character fields in postgresql. Excluding spaces in the result as well. I want to be able to see only all non-alpha numeric characters in my result.

**Example:**

```
First Name | Last Name
ABC&DEF    | GHIJ\
```

**Result:**

```
First Name | Last Name
&          | \
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try before you posted this? Where did you get stuck when you tried to solve it yourself, or read other existing answers?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select regexp_replace(first_name,'[A-Za-z]','','g'), regexp_replace(last_name,'[A-Za-z]','','g') from table_name;
```